# Exception handling for common lisp package enumeration

Tags: exception, common-lisp

So running this lisp code to get all symbols in the common-lisp-user package:

(do-symbols (sym 'common-lisp-user) (print sym))

I get this error:

*** - PRINT: Character #\u0420 cannot be represented in the character set CHARSET:CP437

I'm not extremely familiar with exception handling in Common Lisp.  I've tried handler-case, and restarts, etc, but I haven't yet been able to trap the error and then just carry on.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

FYI, this is on a windows machine running GNU CLISP 2.49.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `(IGNORE-ERRORS (some-form))` ??

Comment: This seems to work -- I'd like to now some how figure out which of the symbols (and replacing non code page characters with their escapes).  Maybe there is still something I can do to capture this error and do a find-replace on the string.

Comment: You have a symbol that has &#1056; (that's a Cyrillic capital ER, not a P) in its name.