# Character #\u009C cannot be represented in the character set CHARSET:CP1252 - how to fix it

Tags: character-encoding, common-lisp

As already pointed out in the topic, I got the following error:

```
Character #\u009C cannot be represented in the character set CHARSET:CP1252
```

trying to print out a string given back by `drakma:http-request`, as far as I understand the error-code the problem is that the windows-encoding (CP1252) does not support this character.
Therefore to be able to process it, I might/must convert the whole string.

My question is **what package/library does support converting strings to certain character-sets efficiently?**

An alike question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143418/exception-handling-for-common-lisp-package-enumeration), but just ignoring the error would not help in my case.

Comment: A precise answer requires some more context (Lisp implementation, operating system, if possible the URL of the page you're having trouble with). With the available information, I can only suggest looking at [babel](http://common-lisp.net/project/babel/), and trying to force drakma to return a binary representation of the response.

Comment: Note that U+009C "almost undefined" in Unicode: it is an extremely rarely used control character. So it is quite unlikely that your string is actually _supposed_ to contain it. Probably the problem is at the _input_ side of your program (where something incorrectly gets decoded into U+009C) rather than something about the output side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drakma already does the job of "converting strings": after all, when it reads from some random webserver, it just gets a stream of bytes. It then has to convert that to a lisp string. You probably want to bind `*drakma-default-external-format*` to something else, although I can't remember off-hand what the allowable values are. Maybe something like `:utf-8`?

Comment: Oh, and looking at the linked question, it seems that Drakma might have correctly interpreted the byte stream, but then your lisp implementation is running in some crappy windows codepage thing. You can see which of the two is going on by looking at the backtrace from the error. Without more info, it'll be difficult to help you further.